# Route returning blank page [METEOR]

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am trying to create a route for a user profile page, but when I visit the route it shows up as a completely blank page and with no errors in the terminal. Nothing whatsoever is shown, including static HTML. Here's the code:

routes.js

```
Router.route('/user/:_id', function () {
  this.render('user');
}, {
  name: 'user',
  data: function(){
    return Users.findOne({_id: this.params._id})
  }
});
```

user.html

```
<template name="user">
    <p>hello</p>
</template>
```

At the moment, I am using the default user accounts package and have not added any publication or subscription code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `Users` is an existing collection?

> At the moment, I am using the default user accounts package and have
>   not added any publication or subscription code.

In that case, with autopublish enabled, your problem is probably solved by changing

```
data: function(){
  return Users.findOne({_id: this.params._id})
}
```

into:

```
data: function(){
  return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.params._id})
}
```

although it's strange this doesn't throw an error in your console...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the reason, but I think that with multiple options for the route, you should incapsulate this.render in an action parameter. Something like this:

```
Router.route('/user/:_id', {
    name: 'user',
    data: function() {
        return Users.findOne({_id: this.params._id})
    },
    action: function () {
       this.render('user');
    }
});
```

[Source](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-options)

Answer (score 0):

I get an error in the terminal: "Users is not defined":
http://meteorpad.com/pad/eciFidhwHmLhjWmF3/Leaderboard

In your data function, try substituting `Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.params._id})`

If you fix the HackPad I listed, Meteor.users won't work since the current version of HackPad doesn't support a late enough version of Meteor with `Meteor.users`.  However, if you comment out your data function, you should at least see the page.